# How many minimum days will he take to complete N units of work?

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

A person has to complete `N` units of work; the nature of work is the same.

In order to get the hang of the work, he completes only **one unit of work in the first day**.

He wishes to celebrate the completion of work, so he decides to complete **one unit of work in the last day**.

He is only allowed to complete **`x`, `x+1` or `x-1` units of work in a day**, where `x` is the units of work completed on the previous day.

Your task is to create a program or function that will compute the **minimum** number of days will he take to complete `N` units of work.

#### Sample Input and Ouput:

```
input -> output (corresponding work_per_day table)
-1    -> 0      []
0     -> 0      []
2     -> 2      [1,1]
3     -> 3      [1,1,1]
5     -> 4      [1,1,2,1] or [1,2,1,1]
9     -> 5      [1,2,3,2,1]
13    -> 7      [1,2,2,2,3,2,1]
```

Input may be taken through `STDIN` or as function argument, or in any appropriate way.

Output may be printed or as the result of a function, or in any appropriate way.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution wins.

Comment: Hint: [this integer list](http://oeis.org/A002620) could be helpful.

Comment: So, is input restricted to positive integers, since Kenny showed that it's possible to achieve a negative work count? Or is the work per day restricted to a minimum of zero?

Comment: Why did you accept the Pyth answer? My Jelly answer is 3 bytes shorter...

Comment: Hey,@Dennis I need to understand the approach and @Kenny Lau help me to understand it.

Comment: I am new to CodeGolf so It will take some time to understand all stuffs here fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
×4’½Ḟ
```

This uses a closed form of [@LeakyNun's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78263).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//w5c04oCZwr3huJ7/xbzDh@KCrEf//1stMSwgMCwgMiwgMywgNSwgOSwgMTNd)

Due to a lucky coincidence, `Ḟ` is overloaded as `floor`/`real` for real/complex numbers. This is one of the only three overloaded atoms in Jelly.

#### How it works

```
×4’½Ḟ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

×4     Compute 4n.
  ’    Decrement; yield 4n - 1.
   ½   Square root; yield sqrt(4n - 1).
       If n < 2, this produces an imaginary number.
    Ḟ  If sqrt(4n - 1) is real, round it down to the nearest integer.
       If sqrt(4n - 1) is complex, compute its real part (0).
```

Comment: One does not simply...

Comment: "Lucky coincidence"

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
tfg/*TT4
```

How it works:

```
tfg/*TT4   Q is implicitly assigned to the input.
 f         test for T=1,2,3,... returning the first successful case
   /*TT4   whether T * T / 4
  g     Q  is greater than or equal to the input (second argument implied)
t          and subtract 1 from the first successful case
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tfg%2F*TT4&input=13&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-1%0A0%0A2%0A3%0A9%0A13&debug=0)

In pseudo-code:

```
for(int T=1;;T++)
    if(T*T/4 >= Q)
        return T-1;
```

#### bonus, 22 bytes

"should return 7 for -1"

```
+tfg/*TT4?>Q0Q-2Q1*4g1
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Btfg%2F%2aTT4%3F%3EQ0Q-2Q1%2a4g1&input=13&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-1%0A0%0A2%0A3%0A9%0A13&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES2016), 24 bytes

Shortened version of the ES6 variant below thanks to [@Florent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78255/how-many-minimum-days-will-he-take-to-complete-n-units-of-work/78297?noredirect=1#comment191445_78297) and the [Exponentiation Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation) (currently only in Firefox nightly builds or transpilers).

```js
n=>(n-1)**.5+(n+1)**.5|0
```

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```js
n=>(s=Math.sqrt)(n-1)+s(n+1)|0
```

Based upon [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A000267).

```js
f=n=>(s=Math.sqrt)(n-1)+s(n+1)|0

units.oninput = () => output.value = f(+units.value||0);
```

```html
<label>Units: <input id="units" type="number" value="0" /></label>
<label>Days: <input id="output" type="number" value="0" disabled /></label>
```

Comment: Even shorter in ES2016 (26 chars): `f=n=>(n-1)**.5+(n+1)**.5|0`

Comment: @Florent Wow thanks, wasn't aware of the upcoming exponentiation operator.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <del>32</del> 31 bytes

```js
f=(q,t=1)=>q>t*t/4?f(q,t+1):t-1
```

**Ungolfed code:**

```js
function f(q, t = 1) {
  return q > t * t / 4
    ? f(q, t + 1)
    : t - 1
}
```

It uses the same algorithm as Kenny Lau's anwser but it is implemented as recursive closure to save some bytes.

**Usage:**

```js
f(-1)  // 0
f(0)   // 0
f(2)   // 2
f(3)   // 3
f(5)   // 4
f(9)   // 5
f(13)  // 7
```

**REPL solution, 23 bytes**

```js
for(t=1;t*t++/4<q;);t-2
```

Prepend `q=` to run the snippet:

```js
q=-1;for(t=1;t*t++/4<q;);t-2 // 0
q=9;for(t=1;t*t++/4<q;);t-2  // 5
q=13;for(t=1;t*t++/4<q;);t-2 // 7
```

Comment: It even uses the same variable names as mine :)

Comment: Can save one byte by turning `>=` to `<` :D

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks! It's been a long time since i've not golf. I'm a little bit rusted x)

Comment: `for(t=1;;)if(t*t++/4>=q)return t-1;` is only 36 bytes :)

Comment: @KennyLau but it does not accept any input

Comment: `t=0;while(t*t++/4<q);return t-1;` is 32 bytes!

Comment: I thought hard-coded variables are acceptable?

Comment: `q=13;t=0;while(t*t++/4<q);t-1;` // 8 (KO)

Comment: @KennyLau I've added 23 bytes solution :)

Comment: What does REPL mean?

Comment: I don't know if it's shorter but you can eval the REPL code to use it as a function I.e. `q=>eval('... Code ...')`

Answer (score 2):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language), <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```
i$+$+dc^l_u^^$*%/%_c=:_do
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aSQrJCtkY15sX3VeXiQqJS8lX2M9Ol9kbw&input=MTM)

Does not work for negative inputs.

#### How it works:

```
i$+$+dc^l_u^^$*%/%_c=:_do
i$+$+d                     #n = 4*input-1
      c                    #i=0
       ^l_     %/%_c=:_    #while      > n:
           ^^$*            #      i**2
          u                #                i = i+1
                       do  #print(i)
```

### Previous 30-byte solution:

```
iuc^l_u^^$*cuuuu/%_u%/%_c=:_do
```

Online interpreter [here](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/).

Does not work for negative inputs.

#### How it works:

```
iuc^l_u^^$*cuuuu/%_u%/%_c=:_do
iuc                             #push input; inc; i=0;
   ^l_u             %/%_c=:_    #while        > input:
       ^^$*cuuuu/%_             #      i**2/4
                   u            #                      i = i+1
                            do  #print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 28 bytes

```python
lambda n:max(4*n-1,0)**.5//1
```

Outputs a float. The `max` is there to give `0` for `n<=0` while avoiding an error for square root of negative.

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 11 bytes

```
E:t*4/G<f0)
```

Similar algorithm to @KennyLau except that rather than looping indefinitely, I loop from 1...2n to save some bytes.

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=RTp0KjQvRzxmMCk&input=MTM)

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab the input
E   % Double the input
:   % Create an array from 1...2n
t*  % Square each element
4/  % Divide each element by 4
G<  % Test if each element is less than G
f   % Get the indices of the TRUE elements in the array from the previous operation
0)  % Get the last index (the first index where T*T/4 >= n)
    % Implicitly display the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 8 bytes

```
#X4f)ltt
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%23X4f%29ltt&input=5)

Uses same algorithm as @KennyLau

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 43 bytes

```
f=lambda n,i=1:i-1if i*i>=n*4 else f(n,i+1)
```

Comment: can save a byte by using < instead of >=

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```java
n->(int)Math.sqrt(n*4-1)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY3PDoIwDIfvPEWPm8mI@OdgjL4BXDgaD3OgDqEgKyTG8OxzU84uaZq039f@KjlKURUPq2ppDKRS4zsC0Ehlf5WqhMyP3wUo5jvyvdtMkWuGJGkFGSAcwKI4eoGnku6xefbEcLERCbfed9UNl9rZ89HY6gIaF8dy6jXeTmfJf1H5y1DZxO1AcecI1cgwVkwkS/6N/mMEhNCDVYCvA3wb4LsAT@aAKZrsBw)

No need to check if `n` is larger than 0, because Java's `Math.sqrt` returns `NaN` for negative inputs, which becomes `0` with the cast to `int` we already use for the positive inputs.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->n{n<1?0:((4*n-1)**0.5).to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3hCoIwFIX/7ykuA0FtDleaIVkPEhKrTRJkiptQZM@@ponx/Thwzj3n9sPtZavCRif1Vkd2jnPfT0IVsSAMY5oG1LTX@mON1OYquOFQwCUmMWFkS3aOxJHO7GeyhUOJkB8xSlkWUMnvDxAtjLXqBjMiAPns5N1I4ebW6cucbljp8l7qoTEurX7u5DnRgL2tgOgEk/ieDjB48DshS4ms5eL/5gy441pjyAFXvG5wiaQS9gs)

Saving a byte here with `.to_i` instead of `.floor`.

Support for non-positive amounts of work comes at a cost of 6 bytes (`n<1?0:`).